# facebook login dialog disappears soon after loading

Tags: android, facebook, authentication

I have implemented FB in my application an it is working perfectly in my samsung device o/s 1.5. However in the HTC Evo the FB login dialog disappears soon after loading. it stays for a couple of seconds and vanishes. i have tested it in the emulator 2.2 and it works fine.

what could be the possible reason of the behavior and how can i overcome it?

just found out that it happens when i am logged into facebook in another application. 
however in applications like photoshop express there is no such issue.

Just what am i missing??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same issue. It was because I was connected with the official Facebook application. I disconnect from the official Facebook application and then I was able to launch the login dialog. The problem is with SSO.

I solved it by forcing the login dialog rather than SSO by passing FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH in the authorize methods in Facebook.java.

Comment: I had already done this, and it works as well. Thanks anyways.

Comment: Xavier: thanks for the reply. Is there a way i can be connected to the Official Application but make the sure allow the permission or deny ?

Comment: I dont know if there's a way to connect to the official application. Sorry about that :s

Answer (score 6):

The issue is actually that you haven't set up your Key Hash for your application with Facebook yet which is required to use SSO. FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH actually disables SSO, but this is a poorer user experience.  Instead, take a look at an article I put together after struggling with this issue which describes the correct way to tackle your problem:

http://sean.lyn.ch/2011/07/android-the-facebook-sdk-sso-and-you/

Comment: Hi sean. first of all congratulations for putting up a great blog. Can i put up your blogs URL into my blog for my reader?

Comment: Thanks! Feel free to post a link to my blog post.

Answer (score 0):

I got this FacebookException because of [developers site](https://developers.facebook.com/) was not working.After developer facebook site worked, this issue was resolved.