# layout error:106 width:0 ellipsizedWidth:0

Tags: android, android-layout

I created a Dialog for Facebook login it working fine on HTC Desire and emulator but whenever, I am trying to open it in Ericsson Xperia(2.3.2), Dialog box is not coming in Ericsson a full screen is coming having facebook url page and in the loading time it got disappeared. I am able to hit the URl, the page loding into my screen and getting disappeared and in my Log Cat its an Error is showing having TAG="SkLayout_wtle" haivng "layout error:106 width:0 ellipsizedWidth:0" in value.

This is the URl that i am hitting.

[FacebookMobileUrl](https://m.facebook.com/login.php?app_id=161943750529976&cancel=fbconnect://success/?error_reason=user_denied&error=access_denied&error_description=The%2buser%2bdenied%2byour%2brequest.&fbconnect=1&next=https://www.facebook.com/connect/uiserver.php?method=permissions.request&app_id=161943750529976&display=touch&redirect_uri=fbconnect%253A%252F%252Fsuccess&type=user_agent&fbconnect=1&perms=publish_stream&from_login=1&rcount=1)

If any information is require then let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved by force_login_auth for more info see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5245321/facebook-login-dialog-disappears-soon-after-loading)

Inside facebook.java there is a static int `public static final int FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH = -1;` just pass that int into the first two default authorize methods like:

```
 public void authorize(Activity activity, final DialogListener listener) {
        authorize(activity, new String[] {}, FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH,
                listener);
    }
```

and

```
public void authorize(Activity activity, String[] permissions,
            final DialogListener listener) {
        authorize(activity, permissions, FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH, listener);
    }
```

this will disable the sso which required for the fb login or you can use this [blog](http://sean.lyn.ch/2011/07/android-the-facebook-sdk-sso-and-you/) if you dont want to disable it.