# Android FB Connect

Tags: android, facebook

I am trying to integrate the official FB SDK for android. 
below is the basic code

```
public class FbTestActivity extends Activity {
    Facebook facebook = new Facebook("112374492201730");

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        facebook.authorize(this, new String[] { "email", "read_stream" },

        new DialogListener() {

            public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
            }

            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {
            }

            public void onError(DialogError e) {
            }

            public void onCancel() {

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        facebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

When i open the app the Login or (if looged in) Permission dialog never shows up. Some dialog opens for a few mili secs and closes down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the SSO (Single Sign On) feature of the login.

Following link will help you.

[facebook login dialog disappears soon after loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5245321/facebook-login-dialog-disappears-soon-after-loading)

http://ukgupta.blogspot.com/2011/07/facebook-implementation-into-android.html

Comment: Umesh: can you tell me how to Force FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH ? didnt see any code example so i am wondering

Comment: Its a static final int variable in 'Facebook.java" file inside the FB sdk.

Comment: i got that.. just confused where to place it in the above code ?

Comment: just curious with SSO enabled is there away to automatically accept the permissions of the application we are using ?

Comment: the blog clearly says in point no 1. "by forcing the login dialog rather than SSO by passing FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH in the authorize methods in Facebook.java". 

There are numerous authorize methods in Facebook.java, most of which has DEFAULT_AUTH_ACTIVITY_CODE as an arguemnt. replace those with FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH